# Where and how do you generate a JWT token when authenticating a socket.io connection with Node/React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, jwt

From what I understand about Socket.io, there are multiple security issues, such as those mentioned in [this stack exchange post.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71061/socket-io-client-security)

For my case, I'm using socket.io in Node and socket.io-client for React, and setting up a nice line of communication, however I don't need any login from the client side, since I'm simply querying an external API from the backend and posting results to the front end. So I've decided to use the package `socketio-jwt` to secure the connection using jwt tokens.

To implement, the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-jwt) contains the following example to use jwt authentication:

**Server Side**

```
io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: 'your secret or public key',
  handshake: true
}));
 
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('hello!', socket.decoded_token.name);
});
```

**Client Side**

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {
  extraHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${your_jwt}` }
});
```

My question is this: on the client side *where does the variable* `your_jwt` *come from and how can I generate it?*

Answer (score 1):

The token needs to be generated by the `login` API. The user sends `username` and `password` to a `login` endpoint and then your server returns the JWT.

Now, what is this `login` API?

Most API server implements an HTTP endpoint (`POST /login`). Then the client can save it in `local storage`.

If your app doesn't have an HTTP server to support you can just implement this via WebSocket.

Comment: My post indicated I'm *specifically not using a login flow*.

Comment: @J.E.C. Can you elaborate on the question, because if you don't need a login flow then why do you need authentication (JWT) in the first please?

Comment: I've been under the impression that socket.io must be secured manually, no matter what you are using it for - or maybe I'm wrong? I've thought perhaps its possible for an attacker hijack the socket.io connection and commit a DoS attack, or something else I'm unaware of.

Comment: I think you might get `wss`(WebSocket Secure) and `jwt` (JSON Web Tokens) mixed up. `wss` is used to secure the communication (network) between the client and the server (this should stop most `Man-in-the-middle attack`). `jwt` is for managing a stateless authentication (user identity).

Answer (score 0):

You should have an endpoint in your Node app where you generate JWT, client side will get it from that endpoint, save it in persistent storage and reuse it.